# validates_confirmation_of :message doesn't appear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, validation

subsriber.rb

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_confirmation_of :email, :message => "Your emails don't match!"
end
```

I have this in my rails app. When I create a new record without matching email
Here's my create action:

```
def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new(params[:subscriber])
  if @subscriber.save
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "You've been subscribed!"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

How do I make the error message show up in the view file? I don't see anything in the docs saying I need to add something to my views but the message is not showing up.

Comment: You should check out Simple Form or Formtastic since they both build this functionality directly into the form.

Comment: been meaning to check out both of these, but I think learning how to use those would have taken slightly longer than doing what I was going last night. Was just collecting email addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually do need to add something to your view to show the message.

Rails normally does this for you when you create a scaffold, but if you need to do it manually for a field, you need to add something like this to your HTML template:

```
<%= f.error_messages_for :email_confirmation %>
```

Comment: Finally figured this out by looking at some scaffolding last night. Thanks for the response.